# C, static array in function bad practice?

Tags: c, arrays

So I have a rather simple program. In my main function I have a two-dim array. I want to fill two-dim array with other arrays. So I have a function that returns an pointer to an array that contains the values I want for my two-dim array. I then use a for loop to transfer the values from the array pointed to by the pointer into the two-dim array in main.

Is this bad practice? Or is this fine?

Comment: While the code is lacking, the only answer could be "it depends".

Comment: What's the point? Just have a static global array. Same effect. Or take the array you want to fill as argument and roll the foor loop in the function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Don't *describe* code. Show the actual code (well, an [mcve] of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a problem if your program is (going to be in the future) a multi-threaded program. Consider a scenario where two threads call your function and have a pointer to the `static` array in your function. That'll lead to [*data race*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) and thus [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Worse if it's in a library code, then users of the may not even aware of the data races.

However, if that static array is not going to be modified (.i.e., its values are fixed at initialisation time) and only used for reading its values then it doesn't have the above problem.

I personally avoid them unless I *really* don't have better a alternative.